# Is it possible to use a textbox succeded validation to modify another textbox's value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dom, razor

I'm learning to use razor to create web applications.
I want to modify the following code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.foo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.foo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.foo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

so, instead of just displaying an error, also performs an action if the value is valid, I'm also using the following range validator

```
[Range(5000000, 50000000)]
```

I want to be able to change the following model's text, if the range validator succeds.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.foofoo, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" } })
```